# Add class active to a specific menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code but it does not work as I want, I want to put different classes in both menu as I can do this

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'additional_active_item_classes', 10, 2 );

function additional_active_item_classes($classes = array(), $menu_item = false){

    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $menu_item->classes)){
        $classes[] = 'active';
        }


    return $classes;
}
```

I want to affect the primary menu without the footer menu being affected to set another class to activate the footer menu but if it is not possible I would love only to accept the primary menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different menus in wordpress. Which specifically do you want to affect? Are you referring to the frontend interface that visitors see? Or maybe the backend admin area's sidebar?

Unless there is a specific reason, it would be unlikely to need to add an additional class--the menu items already have a special class assigned to them when they are the current page.

These menu items can be styled with the following css selectors:

admin area: #adminmenu li.current{}

frontend: #top-menu li.current-menu-item{}

If you need additional help, please provide more specific information!

EDIT:

```
#top-menu li.current-menu-item a{
color: blue;
}

.bottom-nav li.current-menu-item a{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: I want to affect the primary menu without the footer menu being affected to set another class to activate the footer menu but if it is not possible I would love only to accept the primary menu

Comment: Okay not a problem. I edited my original post to include the css selectors which will allow you to target the top and bottom nav menu items independently. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: this did not work for me but thank you very much anyway

Comment: In what way did it not work? Please state the steps that you took and what the result was. Also including a link to the website you are working on would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.